# How to draw a binomial option tree graph?

Tags: binomial-tree, graphs

I am writing a paper and need to create a png or jpeg file for binomial option price tree.

In the past I would have used the tikZ package in LaTeX, but that won't work in this case.

So I want a different package than LaTeX/Tikz to draw this graph, possibly in R, python, ....

Can you help?

Comment: Hi TJB, welcome to quant.SE! I would transfer this to http://tex.stackexchange.com/ but you have to show more work or they will just close it. So I will close it here and suggest you try again there.

Comment: See above, here its off topic, they will probably close for lack of detail.

Comment: I am trying to avoid using LaTeX for this project. Instead I would like to know how to do it with R, Python, Matlab, Gnuplot or anything of the kind. Where should I go with that question?

Comment: Aha, so you want to create nice graphics in something else than Tikz? I misunderstood, doubting this one is really on-topic but I'll let the community decide as it might be of interest. For now, have you looked at GraphViz?

Comment: @BobJansen I'll take a look at GraphViz.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In R you can use fOptions package to draw Binomial Tree graphs.

Here is a simple code snippet

```
#Install the package and load it
install.packages('fOptions')
library(fOptions)

#Calculate the value of the option and plot
optionVals<-BinomialTreeOption(TypeFlag="ce",S=100,X=100,Time=3,r=0.05,b=0,sigma=0.2,n=3,title="example binomial tree")
BinomialTreePlot(optionVals)
```

The output is given below (I don't know maybe it can be done more beautifully, this is the default).

[image]